# custom-agent not running in munit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mule

I have a custom agent and I am trying to test the code of the custom agent by creating a simple flow and invoking the agent, but for some reason Munit does not seem to be invoking the custom agent when it runs my flow.  Here is the custom agent xml:

```
    <custom-agent name="createQueueAgent"
        class="my.company.package.QueueManageAgent">
        <spring:property name="queueName" value="queueName" />
        <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </custom-agent>
    <flow name="dummyFlow">
        <logger message="this is a flow" level="INFO"/>
    </flow>
```

And here is how I am invoking it(in a class that extends Functional MUnit Suite)

```
    this.runFlow("dummyFlow",testEvent(""));
```

The flow gets run, but the agent never gets initialized.  This works fine if I just run it in mule.  What am I missing here?  I am running Munit/Mule 3.6(Munit is 3.6.0-BETA1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can unit test the custom agent class but not Munit it. An agent is service which will not be available while you do Munit test.

As you are aware from mule documentation

"An agent is a service that is associated with or used by Mule ESB but is not a Mule-managed component. Agents have the same lifecycle as the Mule instance they are registered with, so you can initialize and destroy resources when the Mule instance starts or is disposed."